# このPythonのコードがUnboundLocalErrorと出てしまう。

Tags: python

卒業研究で画像解析をしてその結果を送信することやらないといけなくて事前に用意された画像解析の行うコードに送信処理を書いたのですがface_recognition_scoreというものに数値が入っておりそれが0.6未満でifに分岐するようにしたいのですが条件式のところのface_recognition_scoreがUnboundLocalErrorと出てしまいます。同じ関数内に処理を書き込んでいるからローカルにはなっていると思うのですが、Pythonのことを全く理解していないのでどなたか詳しい方がいらしたら分かりやすく教えていただけると嬉しいです。

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import mediapipe as mp
import serial

# モデルファイル名
FACE_MODEL_NAME = "../models/face_model.tflite"

# 登録画像ファイルパス
DATA_PATH = '../data'

def read_registface(model):
    # 画像を推論して特徴量のリストを作成する
    regist_list = []
    file_list = []
    for file in os.listdir(DATA_PATH):
        # 画像読み込み
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, file))
        # 前処理
        img_preprocessing = preprocessing(img)
        # 特徴量を取得
        predict = predict_model(model, img_preprocessing)
        # 特徴量を保持
        regist_list.append(predict[0])
        # 画像ファイル名を保持
        file_list.append(file)
    return np.array(regist_list), np.array(file_list)

def preprocessing(img):
    # 画像の前処理
    img_preprocessing = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_preprocessing = cv2.resize(img_preprocessing, (112, 112))
    img_preprocessing = img_preprocessing.astype(np.float32) / 255.
    if len(img_preprocessing.shape) == 3:
        img_preprocessing = np.expand_dims(img_preprocessing, 0)
    return img_preprocessing

def predict_model(model, img):
    # TensorFlow Liteモデルの場合
    # モデルの入出力形状取得
    input_details = model.get_input_details()
    output_details = model.get_output_details()
    # 入力画像設定
    model.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], img)
    # 画像を推論
    model.invoke()
    # 推論結果取得
    embeds = model.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    
    return embeds

def recognition(model, img, list):
    # 前処理
    img_preprocessing = preprocessing(img)
    # 計測開始
    time_start = time.perf_counter()
    # 画像を推論
    predict = predict_model(model, img_preprocessing)
    # 計測終了
    time_end = time.perf_counter()
    # 推論時間算出
    predict_time = time_end - time_start
    # 類似度算出
    max_score = 0
    max_score_index = 0
    # 特徴量をベクトルと見立てて絶対値を算出
    predict = predict / np.linalg.norm(predict)
    list = list / np.linalg.norm(list, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
    # 内積からcos類似度を算出
    vector_list = np.inner(predict, list)
    # 類似度が最大の値を取得
    max_score_index = np.argmax(vector_list)
    # 類似度が最大のインデックスを取得
    max_score = np.amax(vector_list)

    return max_score, max_score_index, predict_time

def main():
    print('準備中')
    # カメラ設定
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('Y', 'U', 'Y', 'V'))
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 360)
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 20)
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
    # 顔検出モデル
    mp_face_detection = mp.solutions.face_detection
    face_detection = mp_face_detection.FaceDetection()
    # TensorFlow Liteモデルの場合
    face_model = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=FACE_MODEL_NAME)
    face_model.allocate_tensors()
    # 登録画像読み込み
    regist_list, file_list = read_registface(face_model)
    # 結果表示用画像
    img_result = np.zeros((950, 380, 3))
    result_cnt = 0
    # 顔認証フラグ
    recog_flag = False
    print('準備完了')

    while True:
        recog_flag = False
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        # カメラから画像読み込み
        return_value, cap = vid.read()
        # カメラから画像読み込み失敗時リトライする
        if not return_value:
            continue
        # 推論用にカメラ画像をコピー
        img = cap.copy()
        # 画面表示用にカメラ画像をコピー
        img_show = cap.copy()
        fd_s = time.perf_counter()
        # 顔検出
        result = face_detection.process(img)
        bboxsize_check = 0
        face_bbox = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        if result.detections is not None:
            for detection in result.detections:
                bbox = detection.location_data.relative_bounding_box
                # 顔のサイズが一番大きい人を抽出
                if bboxsize_check < int(bbox.width * img.shape[1]) * \
                                    int(bbox.height * img.shape[0]):
                    bboxsize_check = int(bbox.width * img.shape[1]) * \
                                     int(bbox.height * img.shape[0])
                else:
                    continue
                # 検出した顔の枠を更新
                face_bbox[0] = int(bbox.xmin * img.shape[1])
                face_bbox[1] = int(bbox.ymin * img.shape[0])
                face_bbox[2] = face_bbox[0] + int(bbox.width * img.shape[1])
                face_bbox[3] = face_bbox[1] + int(bbox.height * img.shape[0])

        fd_e = time.perf_counter()
        print('fd', fd_e-fd_s)

        face_img = []
        if face_bbox[2] > 0 and face_bbox[3] > 0:
            # 表示用画像に顔検知結果を描画
            cv2.rectangle(img_show, (face_bbox[0], face_bbox[1]),
                          (face_bbox[2], face_bbox[3]), (22, 22, 250), 2)
            # 顔を切り取り
            face_img = img[int(face_bbox[1]):int(face_bbox[3]),
                           int(face_bbox[0]):int(face_bbox[2])]
        # 顔認証
        if len(face_img) > 0 and len(regist_list) > 0 and \
           face_img.shape[0] > 0 and face_img.shape[1] > 0:
            # 顔認証結果を取得
            fr_s = time.perf_counter()
            face_recognition_score, index, predict_time = \
                recognition(face_model, face_img, regist_list)
            #スコア送信
            if face_recognition_score < 0.6:
                ser.write(str(face_recognition_score))
                ser.close()
            # 結果表示用画像生成
            img_tmp = cv2.imread(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, file_list[index]))
            img_tmp = cv2.resize(img_tmp, (190, 190))
            # 類似度を描画
            cv2.putText(img_tmp, str(face_recognition_score),
                        (0, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            # 顔の画像を表示用にリサイズ
            face_img_tmp = cv2.resize(face_img, (190, 190))
            # 認証時の画像と登録画像を横並びに結合
            img_tmp = cv2.hconcat([face_img_tmp, img_tmp])
            # 初回認証時は1枚だけ表示
            if result_cnt == 0:
                img_result = img_tmp
            result_cnt = result_cnt + 1
            # 5枚以下は、黒画像を追加
            if result_cnt < 5:
                black = np.zeros((190, 380, 3))
                black = black.astype('uint8')
                img_result = img_result[:(result_cnt)*190, :]
                # 過去の画像と最新の認証画像を結合
                img_result = cv2.vconcat([img_result, img_tmp])
                for l in range(5 - result_cnt):
                    # 下に黒い画像を結合
                    img_result = cv2.vconcat([img_result, black])
            else:
                # 直近4枚の画像と最新の認証画像を結合
                img_result = img_result[190:950, :]
                img_result = cv2.vconcat([img_result, img_tmp])
            fr_e = time.perf_counter()
            recog_flag = True
            print('fr', fr_e-fr_s)

        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        fps = 1.0/(end_time-start_time)
        # 処理速度描画
        if recog_flag:
            cv2.putText(img_show, 'FPS:' + str(fps),
                        (500, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        else:
            cv2.putText(img_show, 'FPS:',
                        (500, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(img_show, 'RecognitionMode',
                    (375, 350), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        # 画像表示
        cv2.imshow('FaceRecognition', img_show)
        cv2.imshow('Result', img_result)
        
        # OpenCVのGUIイベントを処理するためのウェイトかつ押下キーを取得
        key_code = cv2.waitKey(1)
        # Escキー押下でループを抜けてアプリを終了する
        if key_code == 27:
            break

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: エラーメッセージを略さず全てを表示されているままの形でテキストで提示してください。また問題を再現・調査するために必要なデータ等も提示するか入手・指定方法を示してください。こちらのヘルプ記事などを参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: 「このPythonのコードがUnboundLocalErrorと出てしまう。」だけでは情報が不足しています。個人情報は伏せた状態で、エラーメッセージ全文を質問に追加してください。

Comment: もしかしたら`def recognition(model, img, list):`の3つ目の引数が`list`というpythonの組み込み関数名になっているから何か影響が出ているかもしてませんね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

考えられる原因としては、実際には「スコア送信」のブロックのインデントが「顔認証」のブロックと同じレベルになっていることでしょうか。念の為、ソースコードを確認してみて下さい。

```py
        # 顔認証
        if len(face_img) > 0 and len(regist_list) > 0 and \
           face_img.shape[0] > 0 and face_img.shape[1] > 0:
            # 顔認証結果を取得
            fr_s = time.perf_counter()
            face_recognition_score, index, predict_time = \
                recognition(face_model, face_img, regist_list)

        #スコア送信
        if face_recognition_score < 0.6:
            ser.write(str(face_recognition_score))
            ser.close()
```

以下の単純なスクリプトでは `face_recognition_score = 1` は実行されません。つまり、`face_recognition_score` が未定義なので `print(face_recognition_score)` で `UnboundLocalError` が発生することになります。<strike>質問文に掲示されているコードには `face_recognition_score` が見当たりませんが、</strike> おそらく条件式が偽(`False`)になるブロック内で `face_recognition_score` が定義されているものと思わまれます。

```py
def test_function():
    if False:
        face_recognition_score = 1

    print(face_recognition_score)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_function()

# Error occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    test_function()
  File "test.py", line 6, in test_function
    print(face_recognition_score)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'face_recognition_score' where it is not associated with a value
```

Comment: 質問に提示されているソースコードでは質問記事のとおり、`if face_recognition_score < 0.6:`の直前の行で`recognition(face_model, face_img, regist_list)`の戻り値を`face_recognition_score, index, predict_time`に分けて格納しているので、この回答のソースコードは正しいとしても質問内容には当てはまらないかもしれません。

Comment: `face_recognition_score` を見落としていました。

Comment: なるほど、質問時の転記ミスで実際に実行されているソースコードは何かが違っている可能性はありますね。質問者さんの確認待ちでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確認したところ元のコードでスコア送信のインデントの数が顔認証のインデントの数と同じになっていてインデントをずらしたら無事に動作しました。転記の際にミスがあり気付かなかった事申し訳ございません。